# Conditional choice of version

Tags: conditionals, comments

I have a document with several sets of questions clustered in different versions. I would like to be able to choose which version to generate with a single parameter. The document is updated frequently, meaning that I am looking for a modular, simple and efficient way to maintain the file.

So far I have looked into etoolbox (for conditional tests), xparse (for string comparison) and comment packages. The best I have achieved is to use a flag per version and maintain the list of versions in my preamble:

```
\excludecomment{v1}
\excludecomment{v2}
...
\excludecomment{v9}
\includecomment{v10}

\begin{document}

\begin{v1}
This is version 1.
\end{v1}
...
\end{document}
```

This works well but is a bit cumbersome. I would rather not have to maintain the list of versions:

```
\generateversion{v10}

\begin{document}

\begin{version}{v1}
This is v1.
\end{version}
...
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I am looking for the following behavior:

- If `generateversion` is absent and there is no `begin{version}`: do as usual
- If `generateversion` is absent and there is at least one `begin{version}`: take only one (ideally, the most recent one)
- If `generateversion` is present and there is no `begin{version}` or not the right one: issue an error
- If `generateversion` is present and there is right `begin{version}`: take only that one
  Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `If generateversion is absent and there is at least one begin{version}: take only one (ideally, the most recent one)`? can you add more explanation here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could use with the requirements you specify:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

% Conditions:
% 1) If \generateversion is absent and there is no \begin{version}: do as usual;
%  - Met by default, as text will be set as usual.
% 2) If \generateversion is absent and there is at least one \begin{version}: take only one (ideally, the most recent one);
%  - "The most recent one" will be the first one
% 3) If \generateversion is present and there is no \begin{version} or not the right one: issue an error;
% 4) If \generateversion is present and there is right \begin{version}: take only that one;

\newif\ifversionpresent
\newif\ifversionused

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{version}[1]{%
  \ifcsname @generateversion\endcsname
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\@generateversion}=0
      \BODY% Do whatever with the body content (4)
      \global\versionusedtrue
    \fi
  \else
    \ifversionpresent\else
      \BODY% Do whatever with the body content (2)
      \global\versionusedtrue
    \fi
  \fi
  \global\versionpresenttrue% version environment was used
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifcsname @generateversion\endcsname% \generateversion was used
    \ifversionused\else% No or incorrect version (3)
      \@latex@error{Incorrect version or no \string\begin\string{version\string}.}{}
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\generateversion}[1]{\gdef\@generateversion{#1}}% Store version
\@onlypreamble\generateversion% You can only use \generatevesion in the preamble
\makeatother

\generateversion{v1}

\begin{document}

\begin{version}{v1}
Version \texttt{v1}.
\end{version}

\begin{version}{v2}
Version \texttt{v2}.
\end{version}

\begin{version}{v3}
Version \texttt{v3}.
\end{version}

\end{document}
```

Output without any `\generateversion` in the preamble:

> Version v1.

Output with `\generateversion{v2}` in the preamble:

> Version v2.

Output with `\generateversion{v4}` in the preamble:

> LaTeX Error: Incorrect version or no `\begin{version}`.

Without specifying any `version` environment, LaTeX will print whatever it finds in your document body. This is the default behaviour; your "do as usual".

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll have a detailed look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent!! if I knew enough about making packages, I would say something this simple should just be made into a package

Answer (score 5):

In the example below, you do have to generate \ifvone, etcetera, but only have to turn on the one(s) that you want.

```
\documentclass{book}


\newif\ifvone
\newif\ifvtwo
\newif\ifvthree

\vtwotrue

\begin{document}

\ifvone
v1 true
\fi

\ifvtwo
v2 true
\fi

\ifvthree
v3 true
\fi
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem than you, I resolve it but I use Makefile. I think this is the prettiest solution because you don’t need to modify your document just before compiling.

For example, this is the code I use for compiling “offensive version of document” (In my publications, I could use swearwords but in *nooffensive* version they didn’t appear).

## Makefile part

In my makefile I put the following lines in the top of document:

```
ifdef NOOFFENSIVE
TEXARGS += \\let\\isoffensive\\undefined
endif

ifdef OFFENSIVE
TEXARGS += \\def\\isoffensive{1}
SUFFIX  :=${SUFFIX}-offensive
endif
```

And lower in my makefile I define the `COMPIL` action like this:

```
ifdef TEXARGS
  COMPIL          = ${TEX} -jobname=${PROCNAME}  "${TEXARGS} \input{main.tex}"
else
  COMPIL          = ${TEX} -jobname=${PROCNAME}  "\input{main.tex}"
endif
```

Note: It is important to anticipate the case where no option is defined.

## LaTeX code part

In the preamble of the LaTeX project (after package declaration) you have to put:

```
\DeclareOption{offensive}{\def\isoffensive{1}}
\DeclareOption{nooffensive}{%
%\let\isoffensive\undefined
}
```

So you can define command like:

```
 \ifdefined\isoffensive
   \newcommand{\offensive}[2]{#1}
 \else
   \newcommand{\offensive}[2]{#2}
 \fi
```

So you can use it in your project, for example `\offensive{Suck my *ss, b*ch!}{Sorry mister, but I couldn’t}`

Note: The first parameter contain the offensive form.

## Command line part

In your LaTeX project, for compiling with offensive form you just have to do:

```
make OFFENSIVE=true
```

or

```
make NOOFFENSIVE=false
```

And, for nooffensive variant:

```
make OFFENSIVE=false
```

or

```
make NOEFFENSIVE=true
```

By default, if you don’t specify any parameter, you get the *nooffensive* version.

You can also combine this option with others, as example *printable* parameter witch transform clickable link into footnotes.

Answer (score 2):

As you ask for a modular solution, a simple but safer approach, without deal with complex conditional or string comparisons, is maintain each set of questions in separate files (said `A.tex`, `B.tex`, `C.tex`... each with a single line of text as "`This is the version A`", etc. )

Then you can insert the `A.tex` subdocument in the  main document with `\include{A}` and omit this simply with a comment, i.e.,  `%\include{A}` or alternatively, excluding "A" from the list of `\includeonly{A,B,C...}`

If you do not want the `\clearpage` insertion between subdocuments, or you mneed insert some other arbitrary code before/after the subdocuments, instead of the normal `\include{A}` (that is usually used to insert whole chapters), you can use the reimplementation of the `newclude` package:

`\include*[<code before>]{<filename>}[<code after>]`

Note the asterisk and the peculiar position of the optional arguments. Without these options, \include*{A} act is just like a `\input{A}`, with the difference that this way you can still use `\includeonly{}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newclude}
\includeonly{A,C} % just change this list
\begin{document}
\include*{A} 
\include*{B}
\include*{C}
\end{document}
```

This will produce:

> This is the version A 
>  
>   This is the version C

**Note**: It is not clear if you are searching for easy designs of exams or anything else. In the first case, take a look to the [exam topic on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam) and if you are a  Linux user, try also [Auto Multiple Choice (AMC)](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/index.en) to easily select and shuffle questions. This is a program with GUI to print exams and then scoring scanned answers, but is still on-topic here, because the task of the design is just launch the LaTeX editor with a normal `.tex` file that must use the LaTeX package `automultiplechoce.sty`.